# Nightwatch - How to specify number of clients in test file

Tags: javascript, testing, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

I want to test some scenario with n clients.

Of course I can specify number of clients as number of environment to run, f.e:

`nightwatch --env chrome,chrome,chrome`

But, can I somehow specify this separately for every test? Is there a way to specify this in test file? I have tried to modify `process.env.__NIGHTWATCH_ENV_KEY` in my test file, but it hasn't work (as expected).

Comment: are you trying to run the same test in multiple browser sessions? or you are looking for parallel execution of all your tests?

Comment: I am trying to run the same test. In my case I test chat app and I want to test multiple clients case.